# targetting text in between elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
  some text here
  <ul>
    <li>cat1</li>
  </ul>
 </li> 
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>
  random stuff here
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
  </ul>
 </li> 
</ul>
```

Is there a way I can target the text in between the `<ul><li> </ul>` i.e. `some text here` and `random stuff here`? I'd really like to hide this text if possible.

Thanks

Comment: There are ways using the raw DOM API (I'm not sure about jQuery), however, is it not possible to wrap that text inside some `span` element that has a certain CSS class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with removing the text, instead of merely hiding it, you could do this:

```
$('ul > li:has(ul)').each(function() {    
   if( this.firstChild.nodeType === 3 ) {
       this.removeChild( this.firstChild );
   }
});
```

This looks at the top level `<li>` elements, check to see if their `firstChild` is a text node, and if so, removes it.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3B32a/

It would be better to identify the top level with a class on the `ul` elements.

If you actually want to show and hide it, it will need to be contained in an element, instead of a standalone text node.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on patrick dw's solution, instead of removing the text you can wrap it in a tag:

```
$('ul > li:has(ul)').each(function() {
    if( this.firstChild.nodeType === 3 ) {
        $(this.firstChild).wrap('<span class="hidden" />');
    }
});
```

And your CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```